# JPA entitymanager simultaneous connection with more than one schemas

Tags: java, jpa

I have a query that fetchs the data from two different schemas , so, is it possible to connect single JPA entitymanger simultaneously with two or more oracle schema ??? if yes ! the how to do it ???